# How to slice a part of an element using css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css, slice

I have some elements in my template and I want to slice them. I'm using some pictures with transparent areas and a border around the picture. I think it's clear but there's a screenshot, check it. The dark gray area is from background and light gray border shouldn't be in rectangle shape.
[image: elements are like this]

Comment: do you need that image without border?

Comment: Border is added using css, image is sliced using a photo editor software. I want the border to match the shape of image.

Comment: i think there is no possibilities using css styles to achieve this...